# Bulk rename files with random filenames in subfolders

Tags: batch-file, random, file-rename

Okay, so I want to automatically rename many files to a random alphanumeric name, here is the scenario:

I got a folder with multiple subfolders, in each subfolder there are a couple of files named in a pattern like:
**Folder A**

```
ABCDE.a1.ext  
ABCDE.a2.ext  
ABCDE.a3.ext  
...
```

**Folder B**

```
FGHIJ.a1.ext  
FGHIJ.a2.ext  
FGHIJ.a3.ext  
...
```

What I want is the files are renamed to random names, but preserving the suffix and extension, like:

**Folder A**

```
HJGKU.a1.ext  
HJGKU.a2.ext  
HJGKU.a3.ext  
...
```

**Folder B**

```
EOBPZ.a1.ext  
EOBPZ.a2.ext  
EOBPZ.a3.ext  
...
```

Someone knows how to do that in Batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: I slightly modified the code accordingly to the comment:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "alphaNum=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

rem I got a folder with multiple subfolders,
for /D %%s in (*) do (

   rem in each subfolder
   cd "%%s"

   rem there are a couple of files named in a pattern like: ABCDE.a1.ext
   rem I want the files renamed to random names,
   set "ranName="
   for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do (
      set /A "ranNum=!random! %% 36"
      for %%r in (!ranNum!) do set "ranName=!ranName!!alphaNum:~%%r,1!"
   )

   rem but preserving the suffix and extension, like: HJGKU.a1.ext
   ren "*.*.*" "!ranName!.*.*"

   cd ..
)
```

Comment: thanks, this renames the files in the subdirectories, BUT those files need the same (random generated) filename, I mean in my example **all files in subdir A** need the same name (prefix): **ABCDE**.a1.ext, **ABCDE**.a2.ext, .... whereas **all files in subdir B** need a different name (prefix) as in subdir A: **EOBPZ**.a1.ext, **EOBPZ**.a2.ext, ....

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "olddir="
FOR /f "tokens=1,2*delims=." %%a IN (
 'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.*.*" '
 ) DO IF "%%c" neq "" (
 CALL :randomname "%%a"
 CALL ECHO(REN "%%a.%%b.%%c" "%%randname%%.%%b.%%c"

)

GOTO :EOF

:randomname
IF "%olddir%"=="%~1" GOTO :EOF
set "olddir=%~1"
SET "randname="
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
:randnlp
SET /a $=%RANDOM% %% 36
SET /a $$=0
FOR %%s IN (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) DO (
 IF !$$!==%$% SET randname=%randname%%%s
 SET /a $$+=1
)
IF "%randname:~4%"=="" GOTO randnlp
ENDLOCAL &SET "randname=%randname%"

GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Perform a directory scan with subdirectories tokenising on `.` and ensuring there are 3 parts by requiring `%%c` to be non-empty.

Pass the base filename to the `randomname` routine which generates a new random name if it sees a change in the base name.

I've used the magic numbers 36 (the number of characters in the `for %%s` string) and 4 (one less than the number of characters required in the random name)

Build the instruction and `echo` it.

Comment: Doesn't work, `echo`ed it shows that the **subfolders** are renamed, not the files within them. If I change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` it gives me syntax error.

Comment: Possibly you've omitted the `-` before the `d` in the `dir` command.